# Gene expression for mouse feeder cells (inactivated MEFs)

Tags: molecular-biology, rna-sequencing, mrna

I'm looking for a paper with gene expression data for mouse feeder cells, inactivated by gamma radiation or mitomycin C. Ideally I'd like RNA-seq data but I'll use microarray data if that's all there is.

I've spent quite a while looking (in GEO, Google Scholar, PubMed, etc) with no luck. Any leads would be appreciated.